# PhpMyAdmin error #1045 on WampServer

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I have installed `WampServer` on my laptop running `Windows 8.1`. I am getting this error message when opening `PhpMyAdmin`:

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How can I fix this?

Comment: use the correct mysql credentials?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure whether you have no password on your main root account, you should reinstall `MySQL` or `WampServer`. In some cases your error can occur when you have already installed other MySQL versions on your PC.